# psycopg2 does not insert unicode data

Tags: postgresql, unicode, psycopg2

I have a script that takes data from one database and according to tables' names and fields copies it into another database.
The issue is about unicode data, I need to insert some words in Russian but every time psycopg2 writes it as if it were default string.

```
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extensions

conn_two = psycopg2.connect(user="postgres", password="password", host = "localhost", port= "5432", dbname = "base2")
cur_2  = conn_two.cursor()
sql = 'INSERT INTO {} ({})  VALUES {};'.format('"tb_names"', '"num", "name", "district"',  (23, 'Рынок', 'Волжский')) 
cur_2.execute(sql)
conn_two.commit()
```

Here is how the result looks like in pgAdmin4:

[image]

I also tried to set exteinsions and insert data in unicode, but in this case I have an error

```
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extensions
psycopg2.extensions.register_type(psycopg2.extensions.UNICODE)
psycopg2.extensions.register_type(psycopg2.extensions.UNICODEARRAY)

conn_two = psycopg2.connect(user="postgres", password="password", host = "localhost", port= "5432", dbname = "base2")
conn_two.set_client_encoding("utf-8")
conn_two.set_client_encoding('UNICODE')
cur_2  = conn_two.cursor()
sql = 'INSERT INTO {} ({})  VALUES {};'.format('"tb_names"', '"num", "name", "district"',  (23, u'Рынок', u'Волжский')) 
cur_2.execute(sql)
conn_two.commit()


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\_Scripts\pgadmin.py", line <>, in <module>
    cur_2.execute(sql)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: ОШИБКА:  тип "u" не существует # - says that type "u" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ing_ex" ("num", "name", "district")  VALUES (23, u'\u0420\u...
                                                            ^
```

What should be done here?

Comment: Definitely Python 2.x?

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack Python 2.7

Comment: Quick fix - try adding a `u` to your SQL statement: `sql = u'INSERT INTO {} ({})  VALUES {};'.format('"tb_names"', '"num", "name", "district"',  (23, u'Рынок', u'Волжский')) `

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack brilliant! I wrote it in more readable view `sql = u'INSERT INTO {} ({}) VALUES ({});'.format("tb_names", u"num, name, district",  u"23, 'Рынок', 'Волжский'")`

Comment: I think the better solution is to pass the values to `.execute` instead. See answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't prepare your string with the values baked in (using string formatting or concatenation).

Instead, use `%s` in the SQL string as placeholders, then pass your values to the `.execute` method as an argument.

If you're on Python 2.x, non-ASCII strings should be passed as Unicode types.

E.g.

**Python 2.x**

```
sql = 'INSERT INTO "tb_names" ("num", "name", "district") VALUES (%s, %s, %s);'
cur_2.execute(sql, (23, u'Рынок', u'Волжский'))
```

**Python 3.x**

```
sql = 'INSERT INTO "tb_names" ("num", "name", "district") VALUES (%s, %s, %s);'
cur_2.execute(sql, (23, 'Рынок', 'Волжский'))
```

Comment: but i should use string formatting or concatenation? what is the solution please ?

Comment: Please see updated answer, which removes some ambiguity.